# Can file just pass trough the server and to AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, file-upload

I'm trying to upload large file to S3 but:

- without file being stored on the server
- without "upload file to server" and when it's done "upload file to S3"

What I'm trying to accomplish is: as soon as file upload stars - pipe that file upload directly to S3 so that I don't have to wait for file to be uploaded to the server and then wait again for file to be uploaded to S3.

*I've only started using GoLang and I mostly have no idea what I'm doing.*

So far I'm using echo (https://echo.labstack.com).

```golang
file, err := c.FormFile("file")
if err != nil {
    return err
}

src, err := file.Open()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer src.Close()
```

If I understood correctly at this point i have `io.Reader` (`src` variable) and I don't have to wait for file to be uploaded to server, before I can use that reader to start uploading to S3?
Basically while file is being sent to the server, at the same time server is sending the file to S3.

Or am I wrong?
Is it better to use `io.Pipe`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to upload a file from a client (web, mobile, desktop applications) to S3 without storing the file in your server.

A possible approach using official AWS SDK is answered here:
[Upload object to AWS S3 without creating a file using aws-sdk-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621804/upload-object-to-aws-s3-without-creating-a-file-using-aws-sdk-go)

Alternatively, if you want to skip your server entirely for uploading and let your client apps upload directly to your S3 bucket, you might want to take a look at [S3 pre-signed upload URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).

Your server now plays the role of pre-signing the upload request, meaning it will authorize clients to upload the files to your S3 bucket. For large file, you will have to use multi-part upload and your server will need to [pre-sign each part](https://www.altostra.com/blog/multipart-uploads-with-s3-presigned-url).

Comment: I am more interested in how GoLang works. I choose AWS S3 only as an example. There are libraries out there (like Backblaze B2) which don't support generating pre-signed URLs to upload from client side.
Basically what I'm interested in is: Does upload to S3 starts before upload to server finishes? Or do I have to use `io.Pipe` or something else for such behaviour. (To use server only as a buffer of sorts.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't really "have" [io.Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader). It is just an [interface](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9) provided by the [io](https://golang.org/pkg/io) package. [io.Pipe](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe), if you are interested, returns

(*[io.PipeReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#PipeReader), *[io.PipeWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#PipeWriter))

The **io.PipeReader** above is an actual implementation of the **io.Reader** interface - and hence can be used directly in [golang aws sdk for s3](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager?utm_source=godoc#UploadInput) when uploading.

[Here's how **io.PipeReader** works](https://golang.org/src/io/pipe.go?s=2346:2381#L114)